How to select and filter custom fields in the HANA Cloud?
I've added custom fields to the standard S4 HANA Cloud API.
Now I want to filter and select custom fields using SAP Cloud SDK Javascript.
I figure out how to filter custom fields.
serviceOrderApi.customField("YY1_XYZ").edmString().equals('ABC')

Now, I select all fields but it doesn't contain custom fields.
I've tried googling any tutorials and documentation. Nothing found.
Even though SAP documentation doesn't mention how to select custom fields. The only I can find is  https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/js/features/odata/v2-client#custom-fields
How can I select particular custom fields?
UPDATED:
I've found a workaround.

I need to download updated EDMX file from S4HANA Cloud system instead of using the EDMX from SAP API Hub.
Generate odata client then it will have custom fields I need.
I'm able to query and data returned contain custom fields.


yes, this is the recommended way, you can answer your own question if you like.

Assuming you are using the Java variant of the Cloud SDK you can find the documentation for selecting custom fields here for OData V2 and here for OData V4.
Copying an example from the docs:
service().getAllBusinessPartner()
         .select(new BusinessPartnerField<>("ShoeSize"))


Hi MatKuhr, I'm sorry I forgot mentioning that I'm using Javascript version. Thanks for your help.

As you have pointed out it is best to use the correct metadata for the service, because this gives you all of the available features without workarounds.
However you can also achieve this with custom fields like this:
serviceOrderApi
    .requestBuilder()
    .getAll()
    .filter(serviceOrderApi.customField('YY1_XYZ').edmString().equals('ABC'))

